# Django book chapter 7

Tags: python, django

Hi I am working through the Django book and am up to chapter 7. I got the end and was wondering if someone could explain this piece of code for me.

```
<div class="field{% if form.message.errors %} errors{% endif %}">
{% if form.message.errors %}
    <ul>
    {% for error in form.message.errors %}
        <li><strong>{{ error }}</strong></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
<label for="id_message">Message:</label>
{{ form.message }}
<div>
```

I don't understand why you need the first part:

```
<div class="field{% if form.message.errors %} errors{% endif %}">
```

having just:

```
<div class="field">
```

seems to do the same thing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you got an error in your form, the attribute `form.message.errors` will be not empty. So, if it is not empty, the value `'errors'` will be outputted to your html, resulting in:

```
<div class="field errors">
```

It could then be used with a CSS file to display the error message with a special formatting.

Answer (score 2):

```
{% if form.message.errors %} errors{% endif %}
```

This will print the word `errors` if there were any errors passed to the template through your view method.

```
<div class="field{% if form.message.errors %} errors{% endif %}">
```

Here the class `"errors"` is  being added to the div class so if your the form has errors it will generate this:

```
<div class="field errors">
```

This is not really required but may help for styling and identifying the html elements.

Answer (score 1):

If the field has errors that code adds `errors` css class to the `div`. That is useful to highlight the field.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the explanation. I think I understand.

Comment: @TomFin Please accept the answer that you feel is appropriate.